# How to stop users from serial editing that is worth rejection?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

For last few days I have seen few users editing posts in a serial way. I'll be straightforward here, These edits are surely an attempt to gain reputation.

I can say so based on

- A custom, fixed edit summary like "improved question"
- edits are of similar fashion.(eg changing cases of words everywhere)
- edits are done in very short span(eg. 10 edits in 15 minutes)

Such edits are mostly rejected(90% rejected, 10% approved are mostly wrong as well)

I won't name anybody, So I am not linking any edit. But anyone who reviews them must have seen them. I think such edits are waste of everybody's time, so such users must be refrained from doing so.

What are your views on this? How to stop them in short term and long term?

Should we apply a approved/rejected ratio that every user should have to be able to edit posts?(for eg. after 25 edits, a user should maintain 50% approved edits ratio to be able to edit posts further.)

Comment: As far as I know edit bans happen. But they cannot staff off the first wave.

Comment: When a user improves the readability of a post by inserting plausible paragraph breaks **and** corrects spelling errors (more than one :-)) I tend to approve the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

1. Review edits in the queue.
2. Don't robo-review.
3. Edit from the review queue - if you edit and un-check "Suggested edit was helpful" the users edit is rejected, and your correct edit automatically goes through.