# How to tell an editor they are doing something consistently wrong?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Occasionally someone edits a bunch of posts incorrectly in the same way. These edits seem to be made in good faith, but the editor's grammar/syntax/spelling is consistently incorrect. Perhaps this has been covered elsewhere, but how can they be contacted and made aware of their error?

One example I encountered recently was someone trying to change every upper case `I` (i.e. the first-person pronoun) into lower case ones. Since most other parts of their edits were fine, they seemed to be genuinely trying to improve the answer. If their one bad "habit" could be corrected, they could help improve the site.

Would you comment on the post they are trying to edit? But that seems a bit odd, especially if they never look at it again. Just keep rejecting their edits until they stop?

Comment: Please include the suggested edit link into your question.

Comment: @Danatela I really don't think there is any need, Aibara is asking in a general sense.

Comment: I think this is an example: http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/291807

Comment: @Sudheer I hope I pinged you before on this. In case I failed you should review this question to improve your performance. Thank you!

Comment: @Seth anyone who was reviewing edits all know who he is talking about - the other question is - why are some people approving edits like that!?

Comment: It was indeed the user in the example posted by Elder Geek, though I did mean it more generally since I saw something similar a few weeks ago (can't remember what it was though).

Comment: This is somewhat related to my earlier post http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/10428/184942

Comment: Why on *Earth* was that suggested edit accepted, @ElderGeek? *Weird.*

Comment: @TRiG I couldn't say. I would improve it by correcting the obvious or reject it.

Comment: Perhaps a tutorial for editors would be helpful. Something like this: http://vevo.ly/yRwiKB ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is where the `@` replies come in handy.

Users become eligible for an `@` reply on a post if they do one of the following things:

- Vote to close the post.
- Edit the post.
- Comment on the post.

So in this case including `@username` in a comment will ping the user. Write out a nice message explaining what they did wrong and what they should change and *how* to change it (if applicable).

If you find yourself rejecting one of their edits this won't work, so use a custom reject reason instead.

Comment: I just did that: a custom reject reason with @username. A bit of a shame because the edit was otherwise OK. But will the reject reason end up as a message in this user's inbox then? If not, how to reach the user?

Comment: @Jos No, that only works in comments. The only way they will see custom reject reasons is if they check it manually.

Comment: @Seth Just to clarify, if you include `@username` in a comment, will it ping the user even if they haven't responded/interacted with a specific post?

Comment: @AibaraIduas No, it will only ping the user if he/she meets the bullet-ed points above.